# Thread BLOCK issue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, block

I have thread BLOCK issue. Please help me.
In my class, i have two objects. One is for for synchronizing threads and the other is for doing actual business operations.

Here is my Class

```
Class A{
   Object lock = new Object();
   B b = new B();

  public addSomething(){
    synchronized(lock){
       b.doThis();
   }
  }
}
```

I have a single instance of class A that is 'a' and from multiple threads accessing the method a.addSomething(). I am encountering thread BLOCK issue for this.

Comment: You only have 1 method in the class that uses that lock ? Or is that lock used in other places ? You know that threads are Supposed to block until B.doThis() finished, right ?

Comment: What do you mean thread BLOCK issue? Hope the operation `b.doThis()` doesn't block on something like IO?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you (presumably) want it to do.

Comment: Yes i have other methods which are using 'lock' for the synchronization.

Comment: Can't see the rest of your code, but make lock `final` for your own sanity.  Good practice to do that with any member field you can, but specifically with objects you're using as locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably is in `b.doThis()`. If it isn't well-behaved (it takes a very long time to execute or may never finish) all other threads that call `addSomething` will be blocked.